# How to 'fix' potentials $A$ and $φ$ in a region of space?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

Can the magnetic and electric potentials ($A$ and $φ$) be fixed to zero, or at least some constant value in a region of space? Naively, I'd think something like this might work (a hollow conducting sphere connected to a voltage source connected to ground, would the potentials inside the sphere be constant?):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in a conductor you have that inside the electric field is zero so
$
\boldsymbol{E}= - \nabla \phi=\boldsymbol{0} \rightarrow \phi= \text{constant}
$

Comment: Only in static situation, where there are no currents in the conducting objects.